# How to ask for reboot after install with NSIS using cmake

Tags: cmake, nsis

is it possible to ask the user to reboot the system after the end of an installation ?

I am using NSIS with CMake.

Thanks for any help,

Answer (score 1):

You can execute another script from the cmake file by using execute_process command.

Look here [1] for more information.

[1] http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command:execute_process

Comment: How would that work in a nsis installer? Install CMake as part of the install?

Comment: it means that I have to develop an external script that will display a custom dialog box asking the user to reboot the system ? So NSIS could not manage this easier ??